# Twilio Programmable Chat

Tags: twilio, twilio-programmable-chat

I implemented Twilio Programmable Chat chat in my single page application (Angular-2, backend on JAVA).

I noticed that when the app loaded it gets stuck for 3-5 seconds and then everything is back to normal. First, I thought my code is the one to be blamed, but after putting all my code in comment I realized that the line that causing this issue is this:

> Client.create()

Does someone got this problem as well and know how to handle it?

Comment: Could you please share some more code that you have written?